# decoder.container(keyedBy:) throws DecodingError.typeMismatch error. Codable bug?

Tags: json, swift, cocoa, codable

I am using the `Codable` protocols to decode JSON from a Web API.  My `Swift` data model for this API includes both class inheritance (subclasses), and composition (objects as properties of other objects).  In the JSON, the same property name may represent a complete object, or a single string denoting the id of that object in a database.

To my knowledge, the only pattern for handling this sort of JSON using `Codable` is to do the decoding "manually" within the object's initializer `init(from decoder: Decoder)`, and to first try to decode the entire object.  Should that fail (by throwing an error which must be caught), then to retry decoding the same property as a `String`.

This works well, so long as the object containing the varient property is not a subclass of another `Decodable` class.  When that is the case, decoding the properties of the base class will throw the error `DecodingError.typeMismatch` on the call to function `decoder.container(keyedBy:)`.

See my sample code below.

Is this a known bug? And/or am I missing an alternate method of decoding in this situation?

Incidentally, the same error will be thrown within a single function, if `decoder.container(keyedBy:)` is called after a `DecodingError.typeMismatch` error is thrown, even if that error was caught.

```
import Foundation

// A `Base` class
class Base: Codable {
    var baseProperty: String? = "baseProperty"
    init() {}

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case baseProperty }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
//===>> The next line will throw DecodingError.typeMismatch
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        baseProperty = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .baseProperty)
    }
}

// A Subclass of `Base`
class Sub: Base {
    // An `Other` class which is a property of the `Sub` class
    class Other: Codable { var id: String? = "otherID" }
    var subProperty: Other? = nil
    override init() { super.init() }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case subProperty }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        do { subProperty = try container.decode(Other.self,
                                                forKey: .subProperty)
        }
        catch { // We didn't find a whole `Other` object in the JSON; look for a `String` instead
            let s = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .subProperty)
            subProperty = Other()
            subProperty?.id = s
        }
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }
}

// Some sample JSON data:
let json = """
{"baseProperty" : "baseProperty",
 "subProperty" : "someIDString"}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

// MAIN program -----------------------------------------------------
// Decode the JSON to produce a new Sub class instance
do {
    _ = try JSONDecoder().decode(Sub.self, from: json)
}
catch DecodingError.typeMismatch( _, let context) {
    print("DecodingError.typeMismatch: \(context.debugDescription)")
    print("DecodingError.Context: codingPath:")
    for i in 0..<context.codingPath.count { print("  [\(i)] = \(context.codingPath[i])") }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [is a known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6408), which has been fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/13879) (and will make it into Swift 4.1).

The issue is basically that when the decoding of `Other` fails, the decoder will forget to pop off its container from its internal stack, therefore meaning that any future decodes *start* in the nested container for `.subProperty`; hence why you get a type mismatch error on attempting to decode an object from there (as there's only a string!).

Until fixed, one workaround is rather than using `decode(_:forKey:)`; get a *super decoder*, and then attempt to decode an `Other` from that.

So replace this:

```
subProperty = try container.decode(Other.self, forKey: .subProperty)
```

with this:

```
let subPropertyDecoder = try container.superDecoder(forKey: .subProperty)
subProperty = try Other(from: subPropertyDecoder)
```

This works because now we've got a completely new decoder instance, we can't corrupt the stack of the main decoder.

Comment: OMG I so owe you a beer. ;-)